# prepositions "of" or "by" thesis title

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

This is a title of my thesis. I am not sure if the title is clear and if it will be understood correctly by readers. I don't know which of the prepositions is correct in this case.

> Investigation of limitations the Passivhaus concept: Case studies on achievement Passivhaus certification of/by existing passive buildings.

My thesis is about two sustainable design strategies 1. Passivhaus standard (specific requirement must the follow to get their certification) and 2. Passive design. My task is to explore limitation of Passivhaus standard regarding achive this certification in the existing passively designed building.

Comment: The title doesn't make sense regardless of if you put of or by there.

Comment: I'm afraid the title will not be understood. Can you explain in a few sentences what the title/thesis is about?

Comment: Hi everyone! Thanks for spending few minutes and sharing your thoughts. In short, my thesis is about two sustainable design strategies 1. Passivhaus standard ( specific requirement must the follow to get their certification) and 2. Passive design. My task is to explore limitation of Passivhaus standard regarding achive this certification in the existing passively designed building.

Answer (score 1):

The distinction that you specifically are asking about is this.

If you mean that certain existing buildings achieved something, then it should be "by" to be idiomatic. If you mean that the certification pertained to certain buildings, then it should be "of" to be idiomatic. Because the achievement seems to have been certification, the redundant nouns let you use either preposition to express what is not a particularly clear thought.

Because it is literally impossible for buildings, which do not have the mental capacity to set goals or the physical capacity to act in furtherance of goals, the phrase "achievement by buildings" is just a metaphor (and a fairly silly metaphor for buildings that are described as passive). You can make the title clearer by simultaneously avoiding the silly metaphor and the redundancy with "Case Studies on the Passivhaus Certification of Existing Passive Buildings."

But if you want to maintain the sequence of "the achievement of a certification," either "by" or "of" will work because the reader will associate the preposition with whichever noun is applicable.

You did not ask about the proposed title's grammatical errors. "Limitation" requires a preposition: "of" or "on" depending on what thought you are trying to express. "Limitations the Passivhaus Concept" is simply incorrect English grammar.

Furthermore, the proposed title makes little sense. Is it possible for buildings that do not exist to be certified? I suspect that you are referring to certification as Passivhaus of buildings that were designed and constructed in accordance with general "passive" principles but not strict Passivhaus specifications. I can't make any recommendations, however, because it is unclear what you want to say.